# What is the preferred way of listing multiple wheres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which is more efficient (or otherwise preferred): to separate the `where` conditions by commas like this:

```
previous_rsvps = Rsvp
  .where(user_id: array_of_ids,
    waitlist_position: nil,
    and so on...)
```

or to chain them like this:

```
previous_rsvps = Rsvp
  .where(user_id: array_of_ids)
  .where(waitlist_position: nil)
  and so on...
```

or is it better to use SQL ANDs like this:

```
query = <<-SQL
  user_id IN (array_of_ids)
  AND waitlist_position IS NULL
  AND so on...
SQL
previous_rsvps = Rsvp.where(query)
```

I do have some `?` parameters in my query, if that makes any difference.

Comment: It depends on your requirements but i prefer to use `sql` as sql queries operate faster and less burden on server than rails default ORM.

Comment: Thanks, responders. All of the answers were helpful. It's good to know where the tradeoffs lie.  -Shauna

Answer (score 0):

This is more a matter of opinion and preference than anything else. I prefer the approach in your first example since it's a bit more concise and easy to read. They should also translate to very similar SQL so the efficiency should be the same in all cases.

However, there are cases where using the Ruby syntax won't work for more complex queries, such as for unconventional table names, joining across multiple models, and so on. Slo it's definitely important to be familiar with the syntax of the third example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the power of ActiveRecord whenever we can and use the first or second one (I'd use them interchangeably depending of the readability they give me).

Personally, I find it to be a readability issue first, and a maintainability issue afterwards (that's why I would not use the third one unless really needed).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the first version is better in case you wanted to refactor your code and pass around some more parameters or more complex queries, like if you needed to join tables and look within the joint tables:

```
condition = { waitlist_position:nil, user: {email:"some_email"} }
Rsvp.joins(:users).where(condition)
```

Given that condition was dynamically generated somewhere else. That way you keep the `condition` variable in the where and just adjust the criteria somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid chained where calls outside of your model and also keep your query logic inside your model's named scope methods.

```
Rsvp.for_user(user_id)

class Rsvp
  scope :for_user ->(user_id) do
    where(user_id: user_id, waitlist_position: nil)
  end
end
```

This will add more flexibility to your implementation, make it clean and allow to avoid unnecessary code duplication.

Here is very good article regarding the mentioned ideas:

http://craftingruby.com/posts/2015/06/24/say-no-to_chained-scopes.html

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would use the first version. `Class.where(attr1: "lala", attr2: "lelo")`